# Java7 vs java5 garbage collection

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, java-7, java-5

We are planning to migrate our enterprise application currently running on Java5 stack to Java7 stack. We are having issues with **implicit** gc calls (mainly major gc) causing system to be unstable for a short time(ranging from 5 mins - 30 mins). After analyzing the gc stats, we found that **Compact** phase is taking quite long time to complete when compared to Mark and sweep phase. I understand compaction is quite complex and time taking but its impacting the app server which is customer facing and few connections being dropped off during this phase.

Now, my question is as we are migrating to Java7, is there a better garbage collection process compared to Java5?

App servers are provided with decent system resources.

1. Each app server contains 32 cpu cores
2. contains 64 gb ram
3. App server is IBM webpshere server
4. Operating System - 64 bit IBM AIX

As said earlier, gc is happening because of implicit system calls. No explicit system calls invoking gc.

Comment: can you provide GC logs and settings for your java5 configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, my question is as we are migrating to Java7, is there a better garbage collection process compared to Java5?

Generally yes, though as @Pushkar, you should really be migrating to Java 8.

With respects to the specifics of your application(s), it sounds like you need to tune / retune the garbage collection on Java 5.  If you are periodically experiencing 5 to 30 >>minutes<< of unstability due to GC, there is something rather wrong.  The current behavior may be due your application or Websphere (e.g. memory leaks, excessive caching, etc), or it may be due to poor GC tuning.

In short, switching to Java 7 (or 8) might make things better "out of the box", but it is likely that you will need to put in more effort to address the underlying cause of your problems.

Finally, I'd advise the obvious things.

- Implement the changes in small steps.  Don't upgrade your app, websphere version, java version, etc all at the some time.
- Do the upgrades of your servers one at a time.  Have a roll-back plan in case you get unacceptable performance.
- If possible test it all first ... including performance / load testing.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Your suggestions really worked. We cannot migrate to java8 as the framework we are upgrading doesn't support java8. So, we will have to stick to java7. We cached excessively in our application. This might be one of the strong reasons for frequent gc invocation. As a workaround, we turned off caching search results and results are positive. App servers which are taking bot requests are still having the issues and the issue is seen infrequently. Thanks a ton for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad that my suggestions (guesses actually) were helpful to you, but you really do need to make migration of your framework to Java 8 a high prriority.

Answer (score 1):

By default, java 7 uses parallelGC on server class machines. If you are using JDK 7 update 4 or later version, switch to G1 garbage collector which might give you better performance. But as @the8472 suggested,it will be good to know what settings you used in java 5 and now in your current environment.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 reached end of life around April 2015. Why not migrate to 1.8?

GC performance usually improves with java major releases (and in some cases with minor GCs).

You should take a look difference GC tuning flags, following link may help you
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html

Comment: Thanks Pushkar for your answer. We cannot migrate to java8 as the framework we are upgrading doesn't support java8. So, we will have to stick to java7. We did turn off caching search results and it really helped app servers to survive frequent gc. Thanks and Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As of 2020, the advice would be to go to Java 11.  If you are still stuck on Java 7, you should be eliminating your dependency on the old framework (or whatever) that is holding you back.